# how to sort a string that contains numbers and symbols?

Tags: c++, sorting

i want to sort a linear equation,
the input would be: `3y+2x+6z=7`
the required output: `2x+3y+6z=7`
i used the *algorithm* library but the output was exactly like the input.
of course the code is not complete yet but i need this sort function to proceed and I'm a beginner and i don't know much about sorting.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void fillvector(vector<string>& vect)
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;

    for(unsigned int i=0; i<n; i++){
        string input;
        cin>>input;
        vect.push_back(input);
    }
}

void sortvector(vector<string>& vect)
{
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<vect.size(); i++){

        sort(vect.begin(),vect.end());
        cout<<vect[i]<<endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<string> eqns;

    fillvector(eqns);
    sortvector(eqns);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Any reason you're sorting the vector so many times?

Comment: Your vector has one eleement after `fillvector` because you don't actually parse the input. Fix that first.

Comment: 2x goes before 3y because x goes before y or because 2 goes before 3?

Comment: @juanchopanza  i know that i should sort the unsorted equations only but i just want to finish the the whole code first and then look back at the the things that doesn't make sense in my code.

Comment: @KillzoneKid x goes before y and i want to do it for any form of variables, i mean i want all the variables to be sorted alphabetically

Answer (score 1):

I'd start by creating a `term` class along this general order:

```
class term {
    char variable;
    int factor;
public:
    bool operator<(term const &other) const { 
        return variable < other.variable); 
    }     
};
```

Then you'll separate your equation into some number of terms, sort the terms, and then write the terms back out in sorted order (separated by `+`/`-` as appropriate, of course).